# Mapbox SDK : Unable to authenticate (401) to maven repository for my java project

Tags: java, mapbox, mapbox-android

I try to use the latest version of the java SDK on the maven repository as documented on these pages :
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/guides/install/

I always get Unauthorized (401) error when running `mvn clean package`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project : Could not resolve dependencies for project
project:jar:1.0: 
Failed to collect dependencies at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:jar:6.11.0: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:jar:6.11.0: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:pom:6.11.0 (absent): 
Could not transfer artifact com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:pom:6.11.0 from/to mapbox (https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven): status code: 401, 
reason phrase: Unauthorized (401) -> [Help 1]
```

## Project configuration

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <name>Project Name</name>
    <description>Project description</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapbox.mapboxsdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapbox-sdk-services</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapbox.mapboxsdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapbox-sdk-turf</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>jar-with-dependencies</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>launchClass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>mapbox</id>
            <username>mapbox</username>
            <password>[Token generated on my mapbox account]</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

I don't find any documentation concerning this configuration.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Your repository configuration seems to be correct. So in case that your token is valid.
The issue you have is that maven is not accessing those credentials. The indicator is: unauthorized, not forbidden.

Simply it means that you are not able to login - not that login is successful but you have invalid permissions.

So what you need to add is:  to your pom file to tell maven to search the dependency at the right place and so it is mapped to the configured settings you have.

```
<project>
...
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repo name</id>
    <url>Repo URL to connect at</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```